# What does it mean to declare a variable as a function?

Tags: c++

In the example below I do

```
MyClass a ();
```

I've been told that a is actually a function that returns a MyClass but neither of the following lines work.

```
MyClass b = a();
a.a = 1;
```

So what is a and what can I do with it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        int a;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClass a ();
    // a is a function? what does that mean? what can i do with a?

    int exit; cin >> exit;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `MyClass b = a();` does work; it just won't link because you haven't provided a definition of `a`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've been told that a is actually a function that returns a MyClass [...]

That is a function **declaration**. It just declares a function called `a` and makes the compiler aware of its existence and its signature (in this case, the function takes no arguments and returns an object of type `MyClass`). This means you may provide the **definition** of that function later on:

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        int a;
};

int _tmain()
{
    MyClass a (); // This *declares* a function called "a" that takes no
                  // arguments and returns an object of type MyClass...

    MyClass b = a(); // This is all right, as long as a definition for
                     // function a() is provided. Otherwise, the linker
                     // will issue an undefined reference error.

    int exit; cin >> exit;
    return 0;
}

MyClass a() // ...and here is the definition of that function
{
    return MyClass();
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a default ctor in the context of the `main` scope?

Comment: @RandyGaul: No, that would be `MyClass a;` or, in C++11, `MyClass a{}`.

Comment: This is mentioned in the [c++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ctors.html), for example.

Comment: I think this can be confusing to c++ beginers because of MyClass's int a member.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks. I didn't know you could declare the function inside of another function. And I was confused because in Javascript the Function/Object line is gray.